# PowerDesigner reverse engeering index column missing

Tags: powerdesigner

I am having some issue with validating my physical model against a DB2 V9.7 AIX database by using the "Apply Model Changes to Database" option. After the database was successfully reverse engineered, the Index Columns were missing on the database side.

The index columns are in the database, but PowerDesigner is not picking them up during reverse engineering. I am using PowerDesigner 16.1. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue. The configuration that I needed to change was under Database -> Edit Current DBMS -> Script -> Objects -> Index -> Maxlen. The Max length was too small for the Index name so needed to increase it then it worked.